# Is there a way to create a code snippet with an arbitrary prefix? (VScode)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, code-snippets

I'm looking to create a VScode snippet that would execute on an arbitrary prefix. I'm not exactly sure if a snippet is the right term for it, but here's what I'm thinking:

```js
myFunction();
// Autofill this block
call(myFunction);
//

myFunctionNamedBob();

// Autofill this block
call(myFunctionNamedBob);
//
```

Is it possible to insert `call(anyFunction)` any time I hit enter after `anyFunction();`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vscode snippet to do this but you would have to trigger it manually - it won't happen automatically.  In your snippets file:

In your snippets file:

```json
"call function": {
  "prefix": "();",
  "body": [
    "();\ncall(${TM_CURRENT_LINE/\\s*([^(]+)\\(\\);/$1/});"
  ]
}
```

With this after typing the trailing `();` you have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up the suggestions and select this one.  Demo:

[image: call function snippet]

---

You can get automatic triggering with the extension [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips).  After installing it and following its setup instructions this "snippet" will do what you want:

```
snippet `(.*)\(\);` "call function" A
``
rv=m[0]+ '\n' + 'call(' + m[1] + ');'
``
endsnippet
```

[image: HyperSnips automatic insertion of a snippet]

Answer (score -1):

the extension Snippet Generator does a good creating snippets,
else you can create user snippets by :

- clicking on cmd+shift+p
- type snippets
- select configure user snippets
- new user snippets and there you go you can create it and it links to the snippet by file name
  more infos provided in vs code documentation:
  [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)